# Unable to log out after removing <httpCookies> header in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, httpcookie, form-authentication

I am using ASP.NET MVC for my web site. Previously I have added a below common header in the `web.config` file

```
<httpCookies domain="test.sample.com"  httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="true" />
```

I am using another domain for my web site, `test.sample.de`.

My problem is since I have provided the domain as `test.sample.com` in `httpcookies` header, I am not able to login to the `test.sample.de` domain.

So now I have removed the domain from the `httpCookies` header as follows:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="true" />
```

Now the login is working fine in the `test.sample.de` domain but already logged in user in `test.sample.com` domain is unable to log out. After clearing the cookies, the login and log out function works fine. This issue reproduces only for the users who have already logged in while I did these changes. For new users, this is working fine.

Below is the signout code I have used:

```
FormsAuth.SignOut();
Session.RemoveAll();
```

Now, what should I do to fix this issue? Can I add multiple domain support in *httpCookies* header or what fix do I need to give for my already logged in users, other than asking them to clear their cookies?

Comment: What does cookies have to do with the ability to log out? The logged in status is particular to the web server. You render content based on that. Cookies are just used to get into this state easily, without actually entering credentials.

Comment: but i can get rid of this logout issue only after clearing my cookies in the browser. so i meant this might be one of the cause.